# Parts of a URL: host, port, path

Tags: web-services, path, host

Here is the URL:

```
https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/
```

In my code I have this:

```
Server server = new Server(host, port, path);
```

From the URL, what is host, what is port and what is path? What are the input values of the method?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Host: landfill.bugzilla.org

Port: 443 (default)

Path: bugzilla-tip

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

Comment: Shouldn't the url have "https" prepended?

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately the other answers in this question can be slightly misleading. Referring `landfill.bugzilla.org` to as `host` is correct in this specific example, but if the port was other than `443` then it would be incorrect.

`https://` by default uses port `443`, so you may omit it in the `URL`, otherwise it would of looked like this `https://landfill.bugzilla.org:443/bugzilla-tip`:

- **Protocol**: `https://`
- **Hostname**: `landfill.bugzilla.org`
- **Port**: `443`
- **Host**: `landfill.bugzilla.org` or `landfill.bugzilla.org:443` (depending, read below)
- **Hostport**: `landfill.bugzilla.org:443`
- **Path**: `bugzilla-tip`

`host` and `hostname` are not the same in all instances. For example in JavaScript `location.host` will return `www.geeksforgeeks.org:8080` while `location.hostname` returns `www.geeksforgeeks.org`. So sometimes it's only the "same" when the default ports on the protocol are being used depending.

More info: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

Have a look at this:
http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589

Comment: The link you gave states: hostport = host [ ":" port ], host = hostname | hostnumber. So port is not a part of the host.

Comment: @DaniilLantukhov You are correct, I've updated. Weirdly though is that not all things seem to conform to the RFC standard.

Answer (score 12):

- Host: `landfill.bugzilla.org`
- Port: `443` (HTTPS)
- Path: `/bugzilla-tip`

for more details please read [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)

Comment: Thanks, usr996142. I'm new to this, so I'm not yet used to formatting.

Comment: Thanks. From the link that you referenced: *Note that the "/" between the `host` (or `port`) and the `url-path` **is NOT** part of the `url-path`.*

Answer (score 0):

In your case with Host the code is referring to: **landfill.bugzilla.org** *

Port: By default the https port is **443**, but you should check this.

Path: **/bugzilla-tip**

*Although this is theoretically not quite correct, just put it that way for simplicity.

landfill.bugzilla.org is the URL that indicates to which DNS servers it has to go to resolve the Host name, which is "landfill".

The correct answer at the configuration level is that the host is "landfill" and "landfill.bugzilla.org" is the full URL that tells you what the host is and what server you have to go to in order to find it.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)